# How can I get keywords from Google Adwords Api? Android

Tags: android, google-ads-api

I am following this guide but it seems depricated? Or please correct me if I'm wrong.
There is no kotlin version. I am implementing this part, where we get keyword ideas from API call

https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/keyword-planning/generate-keyword-ideas

But after implementing it I am stuck on a piece of sending parameters. Could you please guide me on where can I get these parameters below

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Customer ID is the account ID of the Google Ads account you want to connect to in order to get keyword ideas.

Available [Language IDs](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/reference/data/codes-formats#expandable-7) and [Location IDs](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/reference/data/geotargets) can be found in the reference section of the Ads API documentation.